# Disable password change in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco7

I am using Umbraco 7.1 with Active Directory authentication. I would like to disable users changing their passwords via Umbraco as our passwords are syncronized via another parent SSO system.

I found a way to hide the tab in Dashboard.config but there is still the Edit Your Profile button that has "Change Your Password". Here is an example: http://screencast.com/t/6FIlBzUmb

```
<!--<tab caption="Change password">
<control showOnce="false" addPanel="false" panelCaption="">
    views/dashboard/ChangePassword.html
</control>
</tab>-->
```

Is there a way to disable password change or just hide it?

For what its worth, I have the setting enablePasswordReset="false" set on all 3 membership providers in web.config.

```
<add name="ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" connectionUsername="USER" connectionPassword="PASS" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" EnablePasswordReset="false"/>
```

Comment: Try adding `allowManuallyChangingPassword="false"` to the membership providers defined in web.config. This requires the user to enter their old password before they can set a new password - if they don't know their current password then this effectively disables password changes.